# How to define irregular service in GTFS

Tags: dictionary, calendar, gtfs, transit, opentripplanner

Does anyone know how I should define a transit service that only occurs on public holidays, in GTFS?

```
calendar.txt as;
'4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20161211,20171209'

calendar_dates.txt as;
'4,20171001,1'
'4,20171002,1'
'4,20171225,1'
'4,20171226,1'
```

This apparently does not seem to work... My dataset also contains normal regular services, and they work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populate *calendar_dates.txt* exactly as you have shown above and put nothing in *calendar.txt* for service id 4

This is permitted by the spec, see

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#calendar_datestxt

and I suspect that inserting an entry into calendar.txt with none of the days set to 1 is confusing validators.

Answer (score 0):

You need to both add new service and cancel the service

In this case, New Year’s Day is added as a Sunday schedule (exception_type 1), with the existing weekday schedule cancelled out (exception_type 2).
In calendar.txt:

```
service_id,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday,start_date,end_date
weekday,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,20140101,20240101
saturday,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,20140101,20240101
sunday,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,20140101,20240101
```

In calendar_dates.txt:

```
service_id,date,exception_type
weekday,20140101,2
Sunday,20140101,1
```

See my blog post : http://transitdata.net/on-calendars-and-calendar_dates/ for more info

Comment: I'll try that out! How would you add an irregular service that only occurs once every 2 or 3 weeks?

Comment: individual calendar_dates for each day that the change occurs on.